# Stopping a service before its inner asynctask is finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-broadcast

Suppose I have a service which is called from a broadcastreceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive( final Context pContext, Intent pIntent ) {
    String intentAction = pIntent.getAction();

    if ( intentAction.equals( TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED ) ) {
        String state = pIntent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE );
        if ( state.equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING ) ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( pContext, OverlayService.class );
            pContext.startService( intent );
            return;
        }

        if ( state.equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE ) ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( pContext, OverlayService.class );
            pContext.stopService( intent );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The service contains an inner asynctask which executes an http request:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand( Intent pIntent, int pFlags, int pStartId ) {
    new HttpTask().execute( getString( R.string.conf_server_url ) );

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I'm wondering what happens when the user decides to hang up the phone before the task is completed. I know that the task will keep on running until it is finished. Does this create a memory leak? My guess is that the service can't be destroyed as long as the task isn't finished. But is it collected afterwards? If not, any suggestions how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep a reference to you AsyncTask and call cancel() on it in the service's onDestroy or whenever you no longer needed it? You'll have to check [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) and then end the task.

Comment: I'd actually like the task to continue executing until it's finished, if that's possible. I'm just not sure if this creates a memory leak, since the service should be destroyed after calling stopService but its inner asynctask class is still active afterwards.